# Is it possible to export postgres database without views?

Tags: postgresql

I check [pg_dump doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pgdump.html), and there seems to be an option that allows to export only views. But is there a way to dump a database without all the views?

Answer (score 2):

There's no option that excludes all views. But there are workarounds.

If you isolate all your views in a single schema (as in `create schema views_only...`), you can use

- either the `-n` or `--schema=public` argument to select only the public schema (might not do what you want),
- or the `-N` or `--exclude-schema=views_only`.

If you follow a strict(ish) naming convention, you can use

- either the `-t` or `--table=something` to select only the tables,
- or the `-T` or `--exclude-table=something` to exclude the views.

Be careful with this. In the relational model, base tables and views share a namespace for a reason--they're supposed to be interchangable. SQL generally honors that part of the relational model. Some people use prefixes for database objects, so "we know whether an object is a view, a table, or a stored procedure that returns a table". If you build views with names like "view_wibble", and later decide to replace that view with a table, you have the distasteful options of naming your table "view_wibble", or rewriting application code, stored procedures, other views, etc to use "tbl_wibble" instead of "view_wibble".

But you can use these command-line options more than once. So you can name each of the views you want to exclude. The is probably the best idea.

```
pg_dump ... --exclude-table=view1 --exclude-table=view2 --exclude-table=view3 ...
```